# Jquery Card Game first-child and clone something wrong

Tags: jquery, html, css

Something i haven't been able to figure out.

Code for creating 6 cards DOM elements: with two sides:

```
 <div class="cards">
     <div class="card">
        <div class="face front"></div>
        <div class="face back"></div>
  </div>
```

Jquery:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  $(".card:first-child").clone().appendTo("#cards");
}

$("#cards").children().each(function(index) {
  $(this).find(".back").addClass(pattern);
```

The code works fine , BUT It seems i **only** clone the **first child of "card"** !
  How come it clones " face .back" element of all the other cards as well and let me aaproach it through jquery , it is not supposed to be cloned. Is it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to amend your selector so that it looks for the first child `.card` element within `.cards`, otherwise it will clone any `.card` element which is the first child of its container - which there will be multiple of after the first addition. Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $(".cards .card:first-child").clone().appendTo("#cards");
}
```